# 404 error (SystemJS) XHR error loading as fusion charts not found

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, fusioncharts

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZgco.png)
    Hi i am using .net + angular 4 whenever i tried to import new module for    example      now i am importing `FusionChartModule` i am getting the following
    do i need to add anything in `system.config.js` file ?

> The error is  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZgco.png"

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
import * as FintTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint';
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular4-fusioncharts';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FintTheme);
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FusionChartsModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> my system.config.js file
>   I had also included my system.config.js file I had also used fusion charts inside this but still I am getting that error

```
   (function (global) {
     System.config({
     paths: {
     // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
     // our app is within the app folder
    'app': 'app',

  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',

  'fusioncharts': 'npm:fusioncharts/',
  'angular4-fusioncharts': 'npm:angular4-fusioncharts/dist/'
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  app: {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    meta: {
      './*.js': {
        loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
      }
    }
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  fusioncharts: {
      main: './fusioncharts.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular4-fusioncharts': {
      main: './index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
 }
 });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using systemjs you have to add FusionCharts to your config.js file in your project directory

```
map: {
...

'fusioncharts': 'npm:fusioncharts/',
'angular2-fusioncharts': 'npm:angular2-fusioncharts/dist/'

},
 //packages defines our app package
 packages: {
 ...
fusioncharts: {
  main: './fusioncharts.js',
  defaultExtension: 'js'
},
'angular2-fusioncharts': {
  main: './index.js',
  defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```

You of course need to adapt the angular2-fusioncharts version if you use a different one, I found this plunker, you can see systemjs + fusioncharts for angular2 there, if you also use angular2-fusionchart it should be the same, otherwise adapt the names and paths.

[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/eNdpQL/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: ye I had tried this also still I am getting same error